# mod rewrite for sub directory inside variable sub directories

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need the following example

```
http://www.domain.com/a/b/$var1/newsubdir/c/$var2/$var3/$foo.mp3
```

to rewrite to:

```
http://www.domain.com/a/b/$var1/subdir/c/$var2/$var3/$foo.mp3
```

My code needs to now call 'newsubdir' instead if 'subdir'. Since this is a subdir inside many different variable subdirs ($var1) it's not just a matter of renaming one folder.

$var1, $var2, $var3 are physical filepaths that are generated depending on the accountid, user, etc (can't be changed right now)
$foo is a filename

So I'm just looking for the appropriate Rewrite Rule that can simply handle "$var1" and basically ignore the rest. I'd like to include "/a/b/" in the rule since there might be other instances of "/b/" in the code that could get caught in this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^a/b/(.+)/newsubdir/c/(.+)/(.+)/(.+).mp3 /a/b/$1/subdir/c/$2/$3/$4.mp3
```

Comment: Thanks! This is simple enough. I'm sure anubhava's answer is sufficient as well. I also came across another issue that is unrelated to the original question but might be useful for somebody using Amazon's S3. I realized that I needed to apply this in my ProxyPass. But didn't realize I needed to use ProxyPassMatch. So it will look something like this: ProxyPassMatch ^/a/b/(.+)/newsubdir/(.+)/(.+)/(.+) http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/a/$1/subdir/$2/$3/$4

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(a/b)/([^/]+)/subdir/(c)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^.]+\.mp3)$ /$1/$2/newsubdir/$3/$4/$5/$6 [L,R=302,NC]
```